# Academic alternative for "It is obvious that"

Tags: synonyms

It would be appreciated if somebody provides a few alternatives for "it is obvious that" which can be used for academic purposes (e.g. thesis).
Thanks indeed.

Comment: *It is obvious that* **can** be used for academic purposes. However, the **meaning** of that phrase, which would hold for any way of paraphrasing it, is something that is suspect, and often inappropriate, for academic writing. IOW, it's not about changing the phrasing, it's about **not saying that**, in any way whatsoever. Unless you really mean it, and it is really obvious. And in that case, there is no reason to look for a euphemism.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is obvious that..."?  So you mean "We have no evidence, but we want to assume that..."?

Comment: Dear @Drew, your comment changed my idea to use this phrase in my academic writing. You correctly pointed out this phrase should not be utilized in academic concept if the meaning was "we think it is obvious".

Comment: Dear @GEdgar, you mentioned the right thing. Thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 4):

It is clear that...

We determined that...

It was apparent that...

Observation showed that...

This (*condition*) made evident that

Depending on what you are reporting, you can use words like conclude, surmise, apprehend, understand, appreciate, to introduce a statement if you are giving facts that then lead you to say something is obvious: "Because the temperature of the mixture increased without an external heat source, it is obvious (or we concluded, determined, surmised, hypothesized, etc.) that the reaction is exothermic."

Comment: I appreciate you for the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

*Undoubtedly* is one of the options.

e.g. "*Undoubtedly*, the bacteria would multiply itself soon."

Comment: Clearly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**self-evident**

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not needing to be demonstrated or explained; obvious. ‘self-evident
>   truths’ with clause ‘it is self-evident that you cannot work 14 hours
>   a day and have time left over for a child’ 
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-evident)

Comment: U.S. Declaration of Independence:  "We hold these truths to be self-evident . . . "

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the field you're writing in, you could use the word *"trivial"*.

> [Trivial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trivial.html): Related to or being the mathematically most simple case. More
>   generally, the word "trivial" is used to describe any result which
>   requires little or no effort to derive or prove.

*Example: A matrix equation **Ax = 0** has a trivial solution **x = 0**.*

Answer (score 0):

**Patent**
 obvious: Their scorn was patent to everyone.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patent